# How to authomatically modify .msapp files using Azure Function Apps?

Tags: powershell, azure-functions, powerapps, powerapps-canvas

For the past days I have been trying to create a script to modify Canvas App (Microsoft Power Platform) source files. Essentially, the idea is to be able of sending a new theme.json file to the function app and receive a working .msapp file. As most of the sources suggest, we can modify a .msapp file by unzipping it, changing whatever file, the theme.json in our case, and zipping it again with the .msapp extension. When downloading the source file, it already comes with a PowerShell 5.1 script that does exactly this:

```bash
$AppName = Get-ChildItem -Directory -Exclude "NewMSAPP", "*RECYCLE.BIN" -Name

$NewMSAPP = ".\NewMSAPP"
# [...]
# # Compress & change extension for new MSAPP file in NewMSAPP folder
Compress-Archive -Path ".\$AppName\*" -DestinationPath "$NewMSAPP\$AppName.zip" -Update
Rename-Item -Path "$NewMSAPP\$AppName.zip" -NewName $AppName".msapp"
```

The biggest problem is that when trying to do this with bash (on Mac and Linux), Python or C#, we get the following error:

[image]

Due to this error, we decided to create the azure function on PowerShell, which led to the same error. The main reason seems to be related to an unexpected behaviour of the `Compress-Archive` on PowerShell 7.2, which is the default and only option on Azure functions. We confirm this by running the code locally in PowerShell 7.2. To shortcut this error, we found out the [PowerApp Language Tooling]https://github.com/microsoft/PowerApps-Language-Tooling/blob/master/README.md), which is a nice dotnet CLI tool that allows you to pack and unpack .msapp files. Thanks to this, we could just add the dotnet package to the `requirements.psd1` and install the package as:

```
dotnet tool update --global Microsoft.PowerApps.CLI.Tool
```

and then create the .msapp file just by:

```
pac canvas pack --msapp ToApp.msapp --sources FromSourceFolder
```

With this, the code runs perfectly locally, we could change our file and pack the folder. However, when running on Azure Function Apps, we got an UnauthorizedAccessException right when trying to install the `Microsoft.PowerApps.CLI.Tool` with dotnet:

[image]

At this stage, we tried to use the runas command to run the command as admin, but we failed. We are wondering if there is a way to either install the Microsoft Power Apps CLI (pac) package in Azure Function Apps, we can not add it to the `requirements.psd1` as it is not a in the [PowerShell Gallery](https://www.powershellgallery.com/); or if there is another way to create this .msapp files using Azure Function Apps, it could be in any other programming language.

For your interest, here is the complete code (I left commented the section where the pac package is installed and used):

```bash
$sourceDir = "TemplateTablet"
#$sourceDir = "TemplateTablet2" # Change "References" to "Src" if TemplateTablet2 is used
$appName = New-Guid

# Decodes base64 string 
$decodedBytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetString([System.Convert]::FromBase64String($Base64String))
Write-Output "App name: $($appName)"

# Creates new folder
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path "tmp\$($appName)"

# Copies template to new folder
Get-ChildItem -Path $sourceDir | Copy-Item -Destination "tmp\$($appName)" -Recurse -Container

# Check if Themes.json file exists
if(!(Test-Path "tmp\$($appName)\References\Themes.json")) { #"tmp\$($appName)\Src\Themes.json"
    # Creates themes file
    New-item "tmp\$($appName)\References\Themes.json" -ItemType File -Value $decodedBytes #"tmp\$($appName)\Src\Themes.json" 
    Write-Output "Themes.json file does not exists. Creating one."
} else {
    Remove-item "tmp\$($appName)\References\Themes.json" #"tmp\$($appName)\Src\Themes.json"
    New-item "tmp\$($appName)\References\Themes.json" -ItemType File -Value $decodedBytes #"tmp\$($appName)\Src\Themes.json" 
    Write-Output "Themes.json already exists. Deleting and creating new one."
}

# zip and rename folder
Compress-Archive -Path "tmp\$($appName)\*" -DestinationPath "tmp\$($appName).zip" -Update
Rename-Item -Path "tmp\$($appName).zip" -NewName $appName".msapp"

# dotnet tool update --global Microsoft.PowerApps.CLI.Tool
# pac canvas pack --sources "tmp\$($appName)" --msapp "HelloWorld.msapp"
# pac canvas pack --sources "tmp\$($appName)\" --msapp HelloWorld.msapp

# Encoding file to b64
```

SOLUTION:

After several atemps, we manage to solve this error by simply editing the zip folder (this is the .msapp file) without unzipping it. This way we manage to avoid the process of zipping back the folder, as it is the process that was breaking our .msapp files.

Comment: I was facing the same issue. Rezipping the .msapp file in PowerShell 5 is working with Compress-Archive. Doesn't work in PowerShell 7. Even tried using TAR and 7zip. Both also don't work. Using the dotnet cli tool works for me.

Comment: Hi Danny, dotnet cli tool actually worked for us, but we were not able of installing it when using Azure Function Apps, as you do not have the authorization. However, we manage to solve these issues by just changing the Theme.json file inside the .msapp file, without unzipping it. Still, I am happy to see that you took your time to answer and remind me I should Edit the question.